# Why does only the sound track of an mp4 video in HTML5 play if it isn't physically first in the code?

Tags: html, video

In the code below, only the physically first mp4 video is played. With the others, only the sound track is played. The videos are selected by clicking on defined areas. This is done correctly (i.e., I hear the expected sound track).

I tried preload = "none" and I tried rearranging the order of the videos in my code. But the result is always the same: whichever video is physically first in the code is the one that gets played correctly.

```
<img src = "musicians.png" width = "1024" height = "770" alt = "'Project'" 
usemap = "#projectmap">

<audio id = "C1">
   <source src = "clip2.mp3" type = "audio/mp3">
</audio>

<video id = "C2" width = "576" height = "720">
   <source src = "Trumpet.mp4" type = "video/mp4">
<video>

<audio id = "C3">
   <source src = "clip9.mp3" type = "audio/mp3">
</audio>

<video id = "C4" width = "576" height = "720">
   <source src = "Guitar.mp4" type = "video/mp4">   
</video>

<audio id = "C5">
   <source src = "clip1.mp3" type = "audio/mp3"> 
</audio>

<video id = "C6" width = "576" height = "720">
   <source src = "Drums.mp4" type = "video/mp4">
</video>

<video id = "C7" width = "576" height = "720">
   <source src = "Flute.mp4" type = "video/mp4">
</video>
```

Each time I click on a defined area in the map, I should see and hear the selected video. This happens for id = C2 in my code, but for C4, C6, and C7 all I get is the sound track. If I change the order of the video tags, the video that is now physically first in the code will be played correctly.

Comment: **Typo:** `<video id = "C2" width = "576" height = "720">
   <source src = "Trumpet.mp4" type = "video/mp4">
<video>` closing tag is an opening one.

Comment: I fixed the typo and still get the same behavior. However, thanks for pointing it out.